# Center track (geoJSON data) on leaflet map

Tags: leaflet, geojson

I have added a track (geoJSON data) to a leaflet (1.5.1) map. Is there a way to calculate the zoom and the map center so that the whole track is displayed?

That's how it's been with me so far:

```
<script>
var map = new L.Map('map');
var osm = new L.TileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {   
    minZoom: 0, 
    maxZoom: 20,    
    attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
});
map.setView(new L.LatLng(49.058744, 8.264556), 12);
map.addLayer(osm);
var track = {   
    "type": "FeatureCollection",    
    "features": [{      
        "type": "Feature",      
        "properties": {         
            "name": "Point",            
            "stroke": "#FF0000",            
            "stroke-width": "4"     
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "LineString",
            "coordinates": [[8.264556,49.058744],[8.264556,49.058745],[8.264574,49.058747],[8.264599,49.058747],[8.264621,49.058743],[8.264628,49.058732]]
        }
    }
]};
L.geoJSON(track).addTo(map);
</script>
```

Comment: Probably answered by https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/167425/44918

Comment: @nikoshr Thank you very much. That's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Duplicate of https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/166863/how-to-calculate-the-bounding-box-of-a-geojson-object-using-python-or-javascript/167425#167425